# Undefined Python references in g++

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am using the following command:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/panda3d -L/usr/lib -o "panda3dplayground"  ./main.o   -lpython2.7 -lp3pystub -lp3framework -lpandafx -lp3pystub -lpandaexpress -lpanda -lp3framework -lp3direct
```

And I am getting the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Cmp'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_FromWideChar'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItem'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_ValueError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItemString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyType_IsSubtype'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Fetch'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_StandardError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_AsSsize_t'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyArg_Parse'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpandaexpress.so: undefined reference to `PyString_AsStringAndSize'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_CallFunction'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_Size'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Size'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Print'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_CallObject'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtool.so: undefined reference to `PySys_GetObject'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtool.so: undefined reference to `PyList_GetItem'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_AssertionError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtoolconfig.so: undefined reference to `Py_InitModule4_64'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyModule_AddStringConstant'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyGen_Type'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Compare'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyList_Append'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyMapping_GetItemString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtoolconfig.so: undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTuple'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyTuple_Pack'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Repr'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyList_SetItem'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyCallable_Check'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_ExceptionMatches'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsWideChar'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_AsLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_GetSize'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_RichCompareBool'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyModule_AddObject'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PySequence_GetItem'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_AsUnsignedLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `_Py_NotImplementedStruct'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PySequence_Size'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_TypeError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyNumber_Long'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyEval_InitThreads'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyType_Ready'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyFloat_FromDouble'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_GenericSetAttr'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_IsTrue'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyImport_GetModuleDict'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Free'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyNumber_Float'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyBool_FromLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtoolconfig.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_AsLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_IndexError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_AsLongLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpandaexpress.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_FromLongLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyFloat_AsDouble'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Restore'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_WarnEx'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Type'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_StopIteration'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Type'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_Call'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PySequence_Check'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyType_GenericAlloc'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyModule_AddIntConstant'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_CallMethod'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtool.so: undefined reference to `Py_IsInitialized'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyList_New'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_SystemExit'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_GetItem'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_FutureWarning'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyTuple_New'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyCFunction_NewEx'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libp3dtoolconfig.so: undefined reference to `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyTuple_Size'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PySequence_Fast'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PySequence_Tuple'
/usr/lib/panda3d/libpanda.so: undefined reference to `PyDict_DelItemString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why isn't g++ recognizing `libpython2.7.so`? I checked out and it is located in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Link order matters. Move `-lpython2.7` so that it appears _after_ all the libraries that are missing some of its functions.

Comment: Check that the architecture of `libpython` (x86/x64) matches that of the rest of your program

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it matches (x86-64)

Comment: @Mat Thanks! That worked. Post it as an answer and make a brief explanation and I will post it as correct

Comment: I've already answered "this question" a few times (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001085/635608) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7330127/635608).) Can't really close as dup since it's not exactly the same thing but it's the same underlying problem. Feel free to post the exact steps you took to fix it as an answer to your own question though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of libraries on the link line [matters](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking), and your order is wrong.

Comment: Hyperlink is broken, please fix.

Comment: @tripulse Fixed.